# How to boost "Big Internet Company" Fiber wifi across the street?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

My startup just moved into our new office. We got a great deal on rent, but unfortunately the building isn't wired for anything but DSL :(.

Luckily, our city has a 1GB Fiber connection through an unnamed "Big Internet Company" and an apartment right across the street has it! We are going to pay the $70/mo for the 1GB fiber and put an antenna in the apartment window to beam the wifi to our office. Luckily as well, we have floor to ceiling windows in our office.

Their apartment is directly across the street (150 feet away), but is blocked by that tree. We're both on the second floor.

Right now, we're thinking about buying an [ASUS RT-AC87R Wireless-AC2400 Dual Band Gigabit Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MPI5N7U) and seeing if that alone does the trick. If not, we're thinking about buying two directional, dual-band antennas (one for sending, one for receiving) to beam the signal to our office.

**What can I do to get the maximum signal strength and down/up speeds in our office across the street?**

Comment: This is pretty broad since you don't have an actual solution in place, so you don't really have a problem to be solved (yet). It is also border-line just a product request (which are off-topic). You seem to know what you want to do, and have some ideas; so go implement them, and then come back with specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am going to have to disagree with you... I have a big problem, I need to get solid wifi from 150 feet away to an entirely different building. I am such a n00b when it comes to networking that I thought I'd ask for some answers to this problem before I go spend $400+ on equipment. Hopes that's ok.

Comment: It's not really "OK", as product request are off-topic, and we don't like dealing with hypotheticals, as there's no way to confirm the answer(s) worked.  You need good antennas and routers/WAPs, that's the answer to your question.  If you want to do the job yourself find something that looks good, go get it, implement it (feel free to come back with _specific_ implementation questions), and then accept responsibility.  If you don't have the expertise, nor are you willing to risk being wrong for $400, then hire a professional.  Regardless, it takes more than just my vote to close this. :)

Comment: BTW... this does violate the google fiber TOS.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about ;)

Comment: I disagree with @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 on this not containing a problem. Problems: What are things to look for in equipment to broadcast this distance through a tree (radio, signal type, directional antennae or not) as well as configuration issues (aim a certain way, make sure you can tell whatever equipment you get to force some strength or broadcast type) - That being said, I think novicePrgrmr should specify these more clearly.

Comment: Thing is 802.11b/g/n really isn't what you want, you want 802.11ac on 5 ghz for the service your planning on using this with.

Comment: @Tyson Good to know, are you referring to the router or the antennas?

Comment: Both... And btw as you study wireless don't confuse 802.11a with 802.11ac

Comment: As you will see when you get your router though, 5ghz (802.11ac) is most likely not going to give you even close to as good of a signal at that distance through objects as 2.4ghz (b/g/n). So even though it has better speeds it will most likely give you lots less stability (disconnects, packet loss, etc). 5ghz bridge (P2P) might work fine, but I would be surprised if the router would @ 5ghz.

Comment: I seen your other post and remember 5ghz is the only band your going to get the speeds your wanting from. Remember this also means if the devices your using don't support 5ghz band then a p2p Link @5ghz will be your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Honestly if your "devices" have a good enough strength, that router will almost certainly boost a 2.4ghz signal to the other location. I would be surprised if the 5ghz would make it very well though as the higher the frequency the worse a frequency is at going through objects. We have a netgear r7000 located in a brick office with big windows, and I can get full bars on 2.4ghz even 150ft away (It doesn't go through our steel shop well though).
- If you get lots of packet loss with just a router though, I've had really good luck with Ubiquiti nanostations. I have a set of nanostation M5's [http://www.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-US-FCC-NSLOCOM5-NanoStation-loco/dp/B004EHSV4W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1412192077&sr=8-2&keywords=nanostation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004EHSV4W) giving me 195Mbps about 1/8th mile apart. A set of nanostation M2's would probably go through the tree better @ only 35Mbps (they also cost less) but I don't think either would be a problem. My only experience with 2.4Ghz bridges is a set of ubiquiti nanobridge M2's. I have these going about a mile with around a woods  @ full strength, but they would be way overkill for 150ft.

Comment: Awesome, we're going to try the ASUS router and see if it does the trick by ourselves. Thanks a ton. I might have some followup questions down the road.

Comment: Sounds good. And if that router didn't work by itself I would buy it from somewhere you can take it back as that would be a crazy expensive/overkill router for just a single office/office use. It's probably overkill anyways but it's fun to have the biggest and best.

Comment: Set up the router today and we're getting 50mbps down and 10mbps up. It's not 1000mbps, but it's plenty for our needs. We're pumped, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ok, I'm wondering if there are any settings I should tweak to improve the signal. Here's a screenshot of what I have right now (default). http://take.ms/0UhID

Comment: As far as I can tell those settings are going to be your best shot at a good signal at that distance. Remember signal is two way though so if a device recieving wifi is too weak for the distance it will have lots of packet loss. That's why even though hopefully a router will be "good enough" but a P2P link would be lots better. 1. there antennas are directional and 2. there "both" high powered. Speaking of this I'm sure they would make directional antennas for routers but idk if that would help things or not.

Comment: We're getting decent speeds, but I wonder if we could get 150mbps+ if we set up either a P2P link or a directional antenna. What would you suggest and what hardware would we want to buy? Does a P2P need clear line of sight? We have a big tree in between the two points.

Comment: The link I added above is the item I think would give you your best chance at those kind of speeds. Only the 5ghz channel would be capable of those speeds. It would require two routers though , as it would basically just act like a wireless LAN cable. I wouldn't think the tree would effect it too much but I don't want to say that for sure.

Comment: Ok awesome to know. Sorry for so many questions, but if I'm going to go the directional antenna route, should I buy two? One for receiving and one for sending? They need to have a "buy me a beer" option on superuser!!

Comment: I would be taking a serious shot in the dark to comment on directional wifi antennas for a router. I've never even looked into this before but I assume they make such a thing? (might not hurt to ask a separate question on that as boosting your 5ghz signal on a router via aftermarket antennas has other factors that could make or break it like if your router will adjust it's tx power to compensate for bigger antennas or if bigger dbi antennas even make much difference since routers are tuned for there stock antennas)And you can suggest a buy me a beer option on meta but it'll proly be rejected=)

Answer (score 2):

After a quick google search, I came up with this antenna. It claims to do exactly what you're looking for.

http://www.radiolabs.com/products/antennas/2.4gig/non-line-of-sight-panel-wifi-antenna.php